# Pyinstaller ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 linking problem

Tags: python, linux, deployment, dll, pyinstaller

I'm trying to deploy my Python based application on another Linux host. Pyinstaller works flawlessly as long as I run the generated executable on my own system.

On the target box I get this error message:

> /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

As the output of ldd shows Pyinstaller links my application against **/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2** which is only available at **/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2** on the target system (where I only have basic user privileges, so symlinking the file is not an option).

How can I modify my executable to look for the library in /lib64/ instead of /lib/ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Python question, but a UNIX/Linux compile and link question.

First of all, are you using the latest Pyinstaller. If not, then try that. If you still have the problem, then please [report the bug to the Pyinstaller developers here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008072304/http://www.pyinstaller.org/report/1).

Try to workaround your problem by using LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the correct directory. For more info read [this article](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html)

Comment: I've tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH without success. I will be reporting the bug to pyinstall developers.