# executable file (created by pyinstaller) requires glibc

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

I created executable file with pyinstaller (in Ubuntu 12.10). It works in other Ubuntu, but when I tried it to run in Debian, I got this error:

```
version GLIBC_2.15 not found
```

Can I run my program on every Linux, which has GLIBC_2.15 and newer? Or how can I check, which Linux is compatible with my program? Thank you for reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761140/pyinstaller-ld-linux-x86-64-so-2-linking-problem?rq=1